# How to sum the filtered data between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to sum the selected data between the two dates and then group it by department. can someone please help me :(
I will attach the rest of the codes here. Please help. I really need this get done. Thanks everyone.

```
SELECT * FROM salary  
WHERE date BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."', Sum (total) as total_salary ] from 'salary' group by department";$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  $output .= '  
       <table> 
            <tr>  
                <th width="10%">Name</th>  
                <th width="2%">Position</th>  
                <th width="2%">Transaction ID</th>  
                <th width="3%">No of Days</th>  
                <th width="4%">Rate Per Day</th>  
                <th width="7%">Undertime</th>
                <th width="7%">Gross Pay</th>
                <th width="7%">Salary</th> 
            </tr>  
  ';  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
  {  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td>'. $row["name"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["position"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["trasactionid"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["days"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["rate"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["undertime"] .'</td> 
                      <td>'. $row["gross"] .'</td> 
                      <td>'. $row["total"] .'</td> 
                 </tr>  
            ';  
       }  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '</table>';  
 echo $output;   }  
?>
```

Im expecting a output like this. With the total salary every Department.

```
Department       Total_Salary
Maintenance      30,000
```

Comment: `SELECT  department, SUM(total) as total_salary 
FROM salary 
WHERE date_time BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_data group by department`

Comment: You are highly vulnerable to sql injection, take care of that. Use prepared statement before querying (use mysqli or pdo)

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari it gives me these error  ''mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean on line 26''
this is my line 26 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

Comment: problem in your script code instead of sql

Comment: @RajendraSingh See the update

Comment: @pogapogipogi try my answer and see if it works.

Comment: just replace if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) with if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) in line 26

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(total) AS total_salary , department 
FROM salary 
WHERE date BETWEEN cast('".$_POST["from_date"]."' as Date) 
AND cast('".$_POST["to_date"]."' as Date) 
GROUP BY department
```

Be careful about using $_POST without validation

Comment: It gives me these error ''mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean on line 26'' this is my line 26 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

Comment: The above error means that your query is running. Are you sure you are trying the correct query above. Can you print the query and try running in phpMyAdmin to see what error it gives.

Comment: Have you tried running my query in phpMyAdmin. When you say it gives no error, does it mean it is returning 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are able to connect to the database successfully. I am also using prepare statement to be safe from sql injection.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT department, SUM(total) as total_salary FROM salary 
                          WHERE date_time BETWEEN ? AND ? group by department");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["from_date"],$_POST["to_date"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();  
$output .= '  
   <table> 
        <tr>  
            <th width="10%">Name</th>  
            <th width="2%">Position</th>  
            <th width="2%">Transaction ID</th>  
            <th width="3%">No of Days</th>  
            <th width="4%">Rate Per Day</th>  
            <th width="7%">Undertime</th>
            <th width="7%">Gross Pay</th>
            <th width="7%">Salary</th> 
        </tr>  
  ';  
  if($result->num_rows > 0)  
 {  
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  
   {  
        $output .= '  
             <tr>  
                  <td>'. $row["name"] .'</td>  
                  <td>'. $row["position"] .'</td>  
                  <td>'. $row["trasactionid"] .'</td>  
                  <td>'. $row["days"] .'</td>  
                  <td>'. $row["rate"] .'</td>  
                  <td>'. $row["undertime"] .'</td> 
                  <td>'. $row["gross"] .'</td> 
                  <td>'. $row["total"] .'</td> 
             </tr>  
        ';  
     }  
   }  
 else  
  {  
     $output .= '  
        <tr>  
             <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
        </tr>  
   ';  
}  
  $output .= '</table>';  
  echo $output;   }  
   ?>
```